# How to get name from either of 2 sub-tables for the main table?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with data as below. I am able to sum the transactions of the AccountIDs, but would also like to get the name of the account which comes from either of 2 tables

```
Transactions: (Type 1=Credit, 2=Debit)
+------------+------+--------+
| AccountID  | Type | Amount |
+------------+------+--------+
| 1000038038 |  1   |  2.15  |
| 1000038038 |  2   |  1.75  |
| 1000038040 |  1   |  1.37  |
| 1000038040 |  2   |  4.82  |
| 1000038040 |  1   |  1.09  |
| 1000038042 |  1   |  5.34  |
| 1000038042 |  2   |  2.43  |
| 1000038060 |  1   |  2.55  |
| 1000038065 |  1   |  3.00  |
+------------+------+--------+

Customers1:
+------------+---------------+
| AccountID  | Name          |
+------------+---------------+
| 1000038038 | Bob           |
| 1000038040 | Jason         |
+------------+---------------+

Customers2:
+------------+---------------+
| AccountID  | Name          |
+------------+---------------+
| 1000038042 | Vince         |
| 1000038060 | Craig         |
+------------+---------------+
```

Now I can get the balances worked out pretty well with the following query...

```
SELECT AccountID,
   SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN Type=1 THEN Amount END,0)) - 
   SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN Type=2 THEN Amount END,0)) AS Balance 
FROM `Transactions`
GROUP BY AccountID ASC
ORDER BY AccountID
```

The above query returns the results as...

```
+------------+---------+
| AccountID  | Balance |
+------------+---------+
| 1000038038 | 0.40    |
| 1000038040 | -2.36   |
| 1000038042 | 2.91    |
| 1000038060 | 2.55    |
| 1000038065 | 3.00    |
+------------+---------+
```

What I would want is to have the names also included which come from either of the 2 Customer tables like below... (note: a/c 38065 is an orphan so it does not have a name associated with it in either Customer table)

```
+------------+---------+---------+
| AccountID  | Name    | Balance |
+------------+---------+---------+
| 1000038038 | Bob     | 0.40    |
| 1000038040 | Jason   | -2.36   |
| 1000038042 | Vince   | 2.91    |
| 1000038060 | Craig   | 2.55    |
| 1000038065 |         | 3.00    |
+------------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   AccountID,
   IFNULL(B.Name, C.Name) AS Name,
   SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN A.Type=1 THEN Amount END,0)) - 
   SUM(COALESCE(CASE WHEN A.Type=2 THEN Amount END,0)) AS Balance 
FROM `Transactions` A 
LEFT JOIN Customers1 B ON A.AccountID=B.AccountID  
LEFT JOIN Customers2 C ON A.AccountID=C.AccountID
GROUP BY A.AccountID 
ORDER BY A.AccountID ASC;
```

See [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) and how to use [MySQL IFNULL function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/) for insight.

Comment: hi here we need to add  Aliases  SELECT   A.AccountID    and A.Amount that will be very clear

Comment: @MathanKumar that's not the intension of the OP.